# Edited: How to use the switch using Bootstrap className?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, ecmascript-6

I can't seem to make the switch work using bootstrap 4.3. I think I am having a problem using bootstrap className, because if I do it without it things are different and works fine.

I have tried setting the label like we do in html, with ids and tagging it to the label, but it also doesn't seem to work.

```
class Privacidad extends Component {
    state = {
        isChecked: true
    }
    toggleChange = () => {
        this.setState({
            isChecked: !this.state.isChecked,
        });
    }
```

```
     <label>
       <input type="checkbox" className="custom-control-input"
                              checked={this.state.isChecked}
                              onChange={this.toggleChange}
                                />
         Si, deseo que otros usuarios me contacten
      </label>

    </div>
```

*Update: To make this work I had to use React-Bootstrap

Comment: `className="custom-control-input"`

Comment: React uses a different class attribute [classname](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#classname)

Comment: Sorry, yes, className... still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `input` for `checkbox` you must use this,

```
<input type="checkbox" 
    className="custom-control-input"
    value={this.state.isChecked} //instead of checked attribute use value attribute
    onChange={this.toggleChange}
 />
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-tdd-knwy2?fontsize=14)

Comment: Thank you, still it doesn't show. It doesn't show to switch control.

Comment: @GabrielMartinez what is the issue, checkbox is not getting selected?

Comment: @GabrielMartinez check the demo.

Comment: Try adding bootstrap, and you will notice that the input disappears

Comment: It's working fine after adding bootstrap, check it.

Comment: Here you can see the one it is supposed to appear: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#switches

Comment: It is working fine, to make it look like your link from comment, make sure to add correct `bootstrap.css` file.

Answer (score 0):

does it working depend on the "custom-control-input" class? Because if so, it's likely not working because you used "class" attribute instead of "className" attribute. React requires you to use className since class is a reserved word.

Comment: No sorry.. is that I have tried so many things, i forgot to replace the class with className. It does not work still.

Answer (score 0):

React uses `className` instead of `class` to assign classes to tags.

```
<input type="checkbox" className="custom-control-input"
                       checked={this.state.isChecked}
                       onChange={this.toggleChange}
/>
```

Comment: Correct, I forgot to update it again, after trying many times. It doesn't work still.